# Windows BAT script for cp alias produces error

Tags: batch-file, chicken-scheme, doskey

I wrote a file called `cp.bat` and the content of this file is: `DOSKEY cp=COPY $* copy`. I saved this file in `c:\users\myname\aliases`. I also added this path to my environment so `cmd` can execute it.

When I now type `cp` in my `cmd` the output is a strange character for the c in `cp`.

[image]

I need this script to work because I want to install chicken scheme eggs on my machine, but the `chicken-install` command executes multiple `cp` commands and those are not recognized in the `cmd`.

I also tried to alter the build script of the eggs, but it gets newly generated everytime I call the `chicken-install` command.

It would also help if someone could explain me how to install chicken eggs on a windows machine correctly. I feel this workaround shouldn't be necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In all probability, your editor is the root of your problem. Batch files should be created in strict ANSI format using a text-editor, not a word-processor. `Notepad` is barely adequate; `Notepad++` is far better - I use `Editplus`

Comment: You were completely right. I opened it in notepad++ and the encoding was set to UTF-8-BOM, I put it to ANSI and saved it. Now it works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Magoo mentioned:

> In all probability, your editor is the root of your problem. Batch files should be created in strict ANSI format using a text-editor, not a word-processor. Notepad is barely adequate; Notepad++ is far better - I use Editplus

The encoding was messed up and it was set to UTF-8-BOM, so I changed it to ANSI and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CHICKEN 5, it should not be emitting `cp` commands; it should emit batch files which use the builtin Windows commands only if you're using the `mingw` platform target.  Have you used the `PLATFORM=mingw` option with every `make` invocation?

If you're using the `mingw-msys` (`or cygwin`) platform, then it will be emitting UNIX style commands.